# C# Unit testing. Verify list count

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I wanted to have a test case where I can verify a list of IRule count increases as new IRule item added. The method I am testing is AddRule. I wanted to keep the 'rules' property private.

Here's the code

```
public class DefaultRulesManager : IRulesManager
{
    private List<IRule> rules;

    public DefaultRulesManager()
    {
        rules = new List<IRule>();
    }

    public void AddRule(IRule rule)
    {
        if (rule == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rule must be set");
        }

        rules.Add(rule);
    }

    public bool HasPassed<T, SKU>(T obj, SKU s)
    {
        IProduct product = (IProduct)obj;

        return rules.All(x => x.HasPassed(product, s));
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your `HasPassed` method would be more cleanly implemented as `return rules.All(x => x.HasPassed(product, s));`. That does have a slightly different behaviour, mind you - it will stop as soon as it finds the first failed rule. If you want all rules to be evaluated even if some fail, you could use `return rules.Count(...) == rules.Count;`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you!

Comment: Expose a new property called `RulesCount` or a method called `HasRule(IRule)` and test against it? Also why `HasPassed` method takes a `T` when you cast `T` to `IProduct`? Can't that be `HasPassed<IProduct, SKU>` or constraint T to be IProduct ?

Comment: Where is the question`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could expose a `Count` read only property that returns the count of `rules`:

```
public int RulesCount 
{
    get { return rules.Count; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are various options here:

- Expose `rules` publicly but safely, e.g. via a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapper or as an `IEnumerable<IRule>` via `return rules.Select(r => r);` to avoid the actual list being exposed via casting. This is reasonable if you have no objection to callers knowing what rules are in a manager, so long as they can't modify the list except via `AddRule`.
- Expose `rules` internally (ideally via a property - I wouldn't suggest an internal field; I'd also make the field readonly), and use `InternalsVisibleTo` to allow your test access to that. (You could expose just the count if you want, but I'm not sure it's particularly beneficial.)
- Stick to testing the public API - you can check whether all the rules you add into the list (in your test) are then consulted.

Personally I'd probably go for the former option - but some people take "only test the public API" as a golden rule never to be broken.

Comment: Is that a good idea?  Pass list as constructor parameter, perform `AddRule` and than make assertions against list.

Comment: @Kote: No, I wouldn't suggest that. Either you'd want to make that internal-only (in which case it's basically equivalent anyway) or it would be public and you'd have a list which you couldn't have control of. There are various ways of achieving the goal with the "internal only" approach, but exposing a property for an existing field seems like the simplest one to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another idea, on the top of previous answers is to perform your unit tests against a class which inherits `DefaultRulesManager`.

You'd have to change `DefaultRulesManager` class slightly by making `rules` member `protected`. Inherited class can be named `DefaultRulesManagerTestable` and provide public readonly property `RulesCount` which would return `rules.Count`.